# plot plane using 3 points in scilab

Tags: plot, scilab

I have three points a,b,c whose x,y,z coordinates are

```
a=[ -0.3519052 0 0];
b=[ 0 -0.674984 0];
c=[ 0 0 -0.6485047];
```

how do plot a plane(triangle) using these three points in scilab
plot3d and plo3d1 are not giving the form i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem!
plot3d1 needs column vectors.

```
plot3d1(a',b',c')
```

produced the plot

Answer (score 1):

**how to plot triangle in scilab**

**Plot a triangle using its sides**

Consider the fist vertex lies at origin(0,0)
Second vertex lies on X-Axis at (a,0)

From distance formula of triangle
ie.

length of side  = sqrt( (x2−x1)^2+(y2−y1)^2 )

Program to Plot a Triangle when sides are given is as below in scilab :

clf()

//Length of the sides

a = 10;

b = 10

c = 10

//Vertex of third point

xc=(a^2-(b^2-c^2))/(2*a)

yc=sqrt(c^2-xc^2);

clf()

x=[0,0,xc]

y=[0,yc,0]

plot2d(0,0,-1,"010","",[0,0,0,0]);

xpoly(x,y,"lines",1)